# How to use socks proxy with Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

By using -http-proxy socks://127.0.0.1:1080 with emulator I got WARNING: Ignoring invalid http proxy: Bad format: invalid proxy name.

What is the argument for emulator to use a socks proxy?